# Guaranteed to have no more than one closure object per local function?

Tags: c#, closures, language-lawyer

I wonder if I can make multiple delegates from a single local function and rely on them to be all equal?

In other words, if I make multiple delegates referencing the same local function, are they all equivalent? Or should I make sure to only create one if I need them to be equal?

Of course, assuming they are all created during a single method call. Otherwise, multiple closure objects must be created.

As an example, is this code guaranteed to always print only one line?

```
class EventSource
{
    public event EventHandler Event;

    public void Raise() => Event?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
}

static class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var source = new EventSource();
        var root = Math.Sqrt(2).ToString();
        void PrintThenUnsubscribe(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Square root of 2: " + root);
            source.Event -= PrintThenUnsubscribe;
        }

        source.Event += PrintThenUnsubscribe;
        source.Raise();
        source.Raise(); // Doesn't print the second time.
    }
}
```

#### Edit:

Here's a simpler example:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

static class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var root = Math.Sqrt(2);
        void print() => Console.WriteLine(root);

        Action a1 = print;
        Action a2 = print;
        Debug.Assert(a1 == a2);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use [sharplab.io](https://sharplab.io/) to see what the compiler does - just set the "Results" pane to "C#" (and add a `using System;`) - but... in short "yes, it will do that today", but this isn't the same as saying "it is guaranteed to do this"; you're right with the "language-lawyer" tag - it would need a specification reference for that!

Comment: @MarcGravell Cool, I didn't know about sharplab.io!